# How can express a sentence containing relative pronoun in Chinese?

Tags: pronouns

I wanted to say "Then I no longer have to listen to the native speaker whose pronunciation I can refer to", but then I realized that I had no idea how to express that sentence in Chinese.

How should I translate this in Chinese? I couldn't make up a sentence better than this" 那么, 我不必听到外国人, 这个人的发音我可以参考. But this sentence sounds a little awkward to me, since it consists of two different clauses, while the English sentence doesn't. Is there any more adequate or sound way to convey this sentence in Chinese?

Comment: Native Chinese speaker or native English speakers?

Comment: Oh.. I'm sorry that I hadn't indicated that. I originally meant to say native Chinese speaker, because the topic of that conversation I had was about studying Chinese.

Comment: relative clauses correspond to attributive phrases (using 的, discussed at this site before)
native speaker? 外国人=foreigner, merely modifying Chinese text provided, 
那么,我不必听到 **其发音我可以参考的** 外国人 Then I no longer have to listen to the foreigner whose pronunciations I can refer to

Comment: w/o 其: 那么,我不必听到可以参考(他的）发音的那个外国人, 那个 can also be put before 可以参考

Comment: Thank you very much for making these comments! but is it possible to put 其 in front of what it refers to??

Comment: according to any dictionary 其 is bookish (书语）for possessive,relative pronouns, his, her, its, their; that, "whose" has to come before what is possessed, i.e. 发音 （their pronunciations)
for more information, in particular about "whose (of whom,which) search web with "英文语法：关系从句" (relative clauses), baidu: (1) They rushed over to help the man whose car had broken down. 那人车坏了，大家都跑过去帮忙。 (here: coordinate (instead of attributive) clause)
(2) Please pass me the book whose (of which) color is green. 请递给我那本绿皮的书。

Comment: search web with ＂英文语法：whose 作关系代词＂ results (from 3 sources): **A** 2．whose表示“他(她)的”，在从句中作定语：
Do you know anyone whose family is in Shanghai?
你认不认识什么人家在上海?
She is the girl whose painting won the first prize．
她就是那个画作赢得头奖的姑娘。 **B**  This is the pencil whose point is broken. 这就是那个折了尖的铅笔。

**C** (1)whose意为谁的，替代的是先行词的所有格形式，因此它不能单独使用，后必须紧跟名词。例如：



Visitors( whose visas are about to expire) are to have them renewed at an early date.

【译文】那些签证即将到期的访问者应该尽早续签。


The child( whose parents died in the car crash) was left in the care of his grandparents.

【译文】那个父母死于车祸的孩子由他的祖父母照看。

Comment: Please consider adding a paragraph...

Comment: 我不须再听那些用以参考的母语人士(来校正发音)了; 我已经不再需要依靠中文母语人士来校正发音了; 我已经不须参考母语人士就能正确发音了。

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

我不用再去参考[那些][中文]母语人士的发音了

would also make sense, since "refer to pronunciation" implies that you would "listen to those native speakers".

If you want to save all words in your sentence, you may translate the attributive clause like this:

我不必再听那些可用来参考的母语人士的发音了。

Answer (score 0):

> - In English, the relative clause follow the object
>
> Then I no longer have to listen to the native Chinese speaker('s pronunciations), [whose pronunciations I can refer to]
>
> 然后我就不再须要听, 母语为中文的人(的发音)[那些我可以参考发音的]"

"*Then I no longer have to listen to the native Chinese speaker('s pronunciations)*" is the main clause, and  "*native Chinese speaker('s pronunciations)*" is the object

"*whose pronunciations I can refer to*" is the relative clause that add information about the object "Chinese speaker('s pronunciations)"

> - In Chinese, the relative clause precede the object
>
> "Then I no longer have to listen to [**whose pronunciations I can refer to**] 
>   the native Chinese speaker('s pronunciations)"
>
> " 然后我就不再须要听[**那些我可以参考发音的**], 母语为中文的人(的发音了)"

Notice you have to add '的' after the relative clause to indicate it is a relative clause for the following object

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this comment! I think I'm getting much better understanding of this matter thanks to this comment. 不好意思, 但我还有另一个问题! 您为什么使用这个'那些'? 是为了包含后面的 '发音'吗??

Comment: '那些'  is a pronoun for "those" -- "那些人" = (those people); " 那些 ~ 的人" = (those who~);

Comment: '那个'  is a pronoun for "that" -- "那个人" = (that person) ; "那个~ 的人" = (who~)

Answer (score 0):

Translating English sentences with clauses, especially long, complex clauses into Chinese is quite difficult. Chinese has no attributive clauses, so it will be **incredibly hard** to conclude the rules of translating such sentences into several handy rules. Each time I encounter such sentence, I will spend quite a long time to find an expression that fits the meaning of the sentence and doesn't sound too weird or too "Anglicized".
A good tip is to try **breaking the sentence with attributive clause into parts**, which means that you should use two or more simple clauses instead of a long sentence with multiple long attributives.
**Example:**
Then I no longer have to listen to the native speakers whose pronunciations I can refer to.
于是，那些可供我参考发音的母语人士，我已无需再听（他们的发音）了。
(Literally: Then, those able for me to refer to (their) pronunciation(, who are) native speakers, I no longer have to listen. )
Although it's not so apparent in this example, it's better than the following translation, which almost directly translates the entire structure as-is:
于是，我已无需再听那些我可以参考发音的母语人士（的发音）了。
P.S. Avoid using two or more attributives with 的 for one head in Chinese! Although it's not wrong to do so, it will make your words weird. If two or more attributives must be used, try to use compound words to replace some  attributives.

Comment: The way you construct the sentence makes it sounds very much like 鲁迅. By saying that I mean, probably that's not the best way to say it in modern Chinese (at least in mainland China).